# Colour interpretation on ASTER GDEM files

Tags: dem, elevation

I'm trying to understand the data in both the grayscale and colorized versions of the GDEM samples provided here: https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

I haven't found (looked hard enough) a definition of the colours. I can see that red is potentially weighted highest or red has an offset or something to boost. Other issue is on the grayscale image the Himalaya ridge is not even coloured particular bright; But maybe there are regions that are boosted as opposed to values, but then I'd expect to see strong region borders.

Right now I can add an offset and scale each channel linearly; So I am looking for a formula/polynomials like from `elev(RGB)=(2000+R*4)+(G*1,1)+(100+B*1,5)` or something like that. And for the grayscale.. I have no idea maybe a non-linear scale (e.g. `G^3 + 0.3*G^2`..idk) ?

Comment: The two image are derived product, they dont hold the data, if you are after elevation you should download the original data

Comment: Right above the greyscale and colour images is the text "*Below are browse images derived from ASTER GDEM globe map data sets. The full data set can be downloaded from the links above.*"